# How can i implement expandAll and Collapse all feature in treetable using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have used this link 
[`codepen.io/sliiice/pen/GurpF`](http://codepen.io/sliiice/pen/GurpF) to implement tree table in my application but unable to create a expandAll and collapseAll feature in it.

Can anyone help me out in implementing this feature in treetable.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-show for this

For example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-click="showFirst = (showFirst ? false : true)"> First
         <ul ng-show="showFirst">
             <li>First > First</li>
             <li>First > Second</li>
             <li>First > Third</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When clicking on First it will toggle the children.